# How to shorten ternary operator further

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ternary-operator

I'm trying to clean up my code and currently have this ternary condition. I would like to clean and refactor it up again and make it short form. How can I counter this?

```
let user = AppDelegate.shared.user!.userID
let messageSender = customMessage.sender.userID
let sender = (user == messageSender)

myCell = sender ? tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) : tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath)
```

Comment: Why is one side of the ternary accessing `tableView` and the other is accessing `pTableView`? Something is very wrong about that. Is it a typo?

Comment: my bad, i have edited it

Comment: Not a fan of this. Adding a third column would be extra work. May as well use a switch case from the start.

Comment: in this case, it seems have only two sides of a chat application. @Alexander

Comment: @RatulSharker And then all of a sudden he wants to support for inline images, which are cells that are distinct from the usual text message cells

Comment: thats legit, but i believe this ternary operation only chooses sides, i'm assuming he had blend all media type in single side custom cell.

Comment: @RatulSharker Different cells can go in the same column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this :

```
let cellName = (user == messageSender) ? "firstCell" : "secondCell"
myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellName, for: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let user = AppDelegate.shared.user!.userID
let messageSender = customMessage.sender.userID
let sender = (user == messageSender)
let reuseIdentifier = sender ? "firstCell" : "secondCell"
let myTableView = sender ? tableView : pTableView

myCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
```